# Formatted Output With Variable Spacing

Tags: java, printf

Is there a feature that supports using a variable in the flag of javas printf method, for example

```
printf("%nd", 12);
```

where *n* is a variable?

I want to specify spacing *outside* of the printf method, for example

```
int n = 5;
System.out.printf("%nd", 12);
```

Instead of the following

```
System.out.printf("%5d", 12);
```

Alternatively, is there any built-in feature similar to that?

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and output you expect? Can you explain your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Let me edit my question.

Comment: Have a look now, I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass the spacing in as part of the data.
You can just build the format string on the fly in your `printf()` statement like so:

```
int n = 5;
System.out.printf("%"+n+"d", 12);
```

Comment: That's perfect. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes . Exists in java `System.out.printf("The date is %d/%d/%d", 1,2,1997);`

Comment: That does not work with a variable as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Build your format string as required and then pass to String.format(). The use of a format string and argument list is identical to its use in `printf()`

```
String myFormat = "...." // build this string with the format you need
String output = String.format( myFormat, ...);
```